# ArrayIndexOutOfBound during loading internet picture

Tags: java, android, inputstream, httpurlconnection, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to load a picture on my android from my server.
I got it to work. But a strangely I got `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in my code below.Since I am using  `HttpURLconnection.getContentLength()` as to generate my byte array, I am unable to figure out why is this happening.  The value from `getContentLength` matched the exact file length on my server so its not the problem in transmission.

As a workaround: I got it to work by adding extra length to the array. This works but I worry the extra length will cause BitmapFactory to produce unwanted result.

Can anybody tell me a solution to this?
Or should I always add some safety and pass the exact length of file to the  Bitmapfactory?

Below is the connection part of my code which goes wrong:

```
   try{
        Log.d("connect_server","is connect");
        URL url = new URL("someurl");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.connect();

        OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        Log.d("post param",params);
        osw.write(params);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        byte[] buf=new byte[connection.getContentLength()+20];
        InputStream src=connection.getInputStream();


        int total=0;
        int amt=512;
        while(amt!=-1){
            Log.d("isloafing",Integer.toString(total));
            amt=src.read(buf,total,amt);
            total+=amt;
            Log.d("is loaDing",Integer.toString(amt));
        }



        Message msg=hnd.obtainMessage();
        msg.arg1=msgTag;
        msg.obj=buf;
        hnd.sendMessage(msg);

    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what type of response are you getting from the server

Comment: You can use Picasso or Glide library to load image.

Comment: @warl0ck The code I post runs on my test phone and loads the picture. So its not going to be 404 or anything like that. Just wanted to know why and if it is avoidable.

Comment: @Dhiren thanks will look at them later. But the only thing I needed now is a solution (without imigrating to some 3rd party  library )on this.

Comment: by response I meant are you getting the image in string form because if this is case you can avoid it all together by reading the complete response in string form and then parse it as it actually is like Integer form like you are doing in your code

Comment: @HarryTheF, its just one line code to load image using Picasso. OK, let me check your code.

Comment: @warl0ck I simply grabs the bytes as  a byte array and  feed it to BitmapFactory.  I worry the pic won't go correct after string conversion.

Comment: if you are getting an array from the server you can get response parse it as array then use it if possible, I can post the answer you can try if it works then good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to get length and all to get the complete response from the server instead you can just check `if the response code is 200 or not`this should do the trick.

To read from the server response you can do something like:

```
private String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    if (inputStream != null) {
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            output.append(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
    }
    return output.toString();
}

 try{
        String response = "";
        Log.d("connect_server","is connect");
        URL url = new URL("someurl");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        OutputStreamWriter osw=new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        Log.d("post param",params);
        osw.write(params);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        connection.connect();
        if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            response = readFromStream(inputStream);
        }

        // now response has your server response use it however you want


    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The `response` string contains the result, you can use it in your project as required